# axios requests throw "Network Error" on Android (Cordova container)

Tags: android, cordova

I have wrapped a `Vue` app into a Cordova container and deployed on Android via Android Studio. Each request that goes out to my server is failing with the message `Error: Network Error`.

This is **not** an issue in browser or iOs.

I have researched this issue and tried various solutions:

1. I have installed the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin and configured as described in the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/)
2. I have set permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<edit-file mode="merge" parent="/manifest/uses-permission" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</edit-file>
```

3. I have setup a `"Content-Security-Policy"` tag in meta:

```
<meta data-n-head="1" http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
```

4. I have changed my server address from `localhost:3000` to my server's IP address as instructed in this answer: [Network error with axios and android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108848/network-error-with-axios-and-android-emulator) - I also tried to run it via a local-tunnel to have a "real" API URL - same issue
5. As instructed in the thread above, I have also added headers:

```
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  Accept: "application/json"
```

Still `Error: Network Error`.
I am almost sure this has to do with permissions but there is nothing more I could configure to make it work.

I am testing this on **Android 10.0+** device using **Cordova 10**.

**Axios** on 0.20.0.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Any update on fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. It looks like Android is not allowing requests to http by default, as stated in this thread: [Internet permission not working in oreo and pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074899/internet-permission-not-working-in-oreo-and-pie)

Changing the localtunnel to `https` solved the issue for me.